# SELECT FROM multiple tables without LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to select `id` from 50 tables with `FIND_IN_SET`. Is there a way to use something other than `LEFT JOIN`? *I gave here only 3 tables because 50 would not fit.*

Note: In each table exist `about_education` column.

The code below cannot work, so what else would I have to do to avoid a thousand lines with the code?

```
nose_1

|id|class|about_education|
| 1|    1|            a01|
| 2|    0|            a02|


coins_2

|id|class|about_education|
| 1|    1|            a01|
| 2|    0|            a02|


money_3

|id|class|about_education|
| 1|    1|            a01|
| 2|    1|            a10|


SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a01', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a02', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a02', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a03', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a04', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a05', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a06', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a07', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a08', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a09', about_education)");
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM nose_1, coins_2, money_3 WHERE class=1 AND FIND_IN_SET('a10', about_education)");
```

Output: 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1

Comment: And where is left join in your example? There is cross join, cartesian  multiplication

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Check now.

Comment: You need `union`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a subquery `UNION ALL` all tables, then `count` function with `CASE WHEN` you can get counts from ID.

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a01' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a01,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a02' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a02, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a03' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a03, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a04' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a04, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a05' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a05, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a06' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a06, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a07' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a07, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a08' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a08, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a09' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a09,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a10' and class = 1 then 1 else null end) a10
FROM 
(
  SELECT id,class,about_education from nose_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id,class,about_education FROM coins_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id,class,about_education FROM money_3
) t
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a87fa/4

**Result**

```
| a01 | a02 | a03 | a04 | a05 | a06 | a07 | a08 | a09 | a10 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|   3 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The `union all` is the right way to go, but I think I would suggest regular aggregation unless you really really want the values in columns:

```
select about_education, count(*)
from (select id, class, about_education from nose_1
      union all
      select id, class, about_education from coins_2
      union all
      select id, class, about_education from money_3
     ) t
where class = 1
group by about_education;
```

Comment: Interesting way you did that. Also will help me.